# Задача по основам ООП (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, методы

Прошу помощи у самых отзывчивых. задачка с *Яндекс Хэндбука*

Рассмотрим объект «Программист», который задаётся именем, должностью и количеством отработанных часов. Каждая должность имеет собственный оклад (заработную плату за час работы). В нашей импровизированной компании существуют 3 должности:
Junior — с окладом 10 тугриков в час;
Middle — с окладом 15 тугриков в час;
Senior — с окладом 20 тугриков в час по умолчанию и +1 тугрик за каждое новое повышение.
Напишите класс Programmer, который инициализируется именем и должностью (отработка у нового работника равна нулю). Класс реализует следующие методы:
work(time) — отмечает новую отработку в количестве часов time;
rise() — повышает программиста;
info() — возвращает строку для бухгалтерии в формате: <имя> <количество отработанных часов>ч. <накопленная зарплата> тгр.

**Примечание**

Ваше решение должно содержать только классы и функции.
В решении не должно быть вызовов инициализации требуемых классов.

**Пример**
**Ввод:**

```
programmer = Programmer('Васильев Иван', 'Junior')  
programmer.work(750)  
print(programmer.info())  
programmer.rise()  
programmer.work(500)  
print(programmer.info())  
programmer.rise()  
programmer.work(250)  
print(programmer.info())  
programmer.rise()  
programmer.work(250)  
print(programmer.info())
```

**Вывод:**
Васильев Иван 750ч. 7500тгр.
Васильев Иван 1250ч. 15000тгр.
Васильев Иван 1500ч. 20000тгр.
Васильев Иван 1750ч. 25250тгр.

*Прикрепляю свой код*:

```
class Programmer:

    def __init__(self, name, role, up=0, n=20, rr=0, sm=0, time=0):
        self.up = up #переменная уровней должностей, начиная с 0 - Junior
        self.role = role #Дожность
        self.name = name #имя работника
        self.n = n #зарплата сеньоров(тгр/ч), получивших повышение(назвал Milord)
        self.rr = rr #суммарное кол-во отработанных часов 
        self.sm = sm #переменная для подсчёта всех заработанных денег работником
        self.time = time # часы работы

    def work(self, timee):
        self.time = timee 
        self.rr = self.rr + self.time
  
    def rise(self):
        if self.role == 'Middle':
            self.up = 1
        if self.role == 'Senior':
            self.up = 2
        self.up += 1
        if self.up == 1:
            self.role = 'Middle'
        if self.up == 2:
            self.role = 'Senior'
        if self.up >= 3:
            self.role = 'Milord'
            self.n += 1
        
    def info(self):
        if self.role == 'Junior':
            self.sm = self.time * 10
            return f'{self.name} {self.time}ч. {self.sm}тгр.'
        if self.role == 'Middle':
            self.sm = (self.time * 15) + self.sm
            return f'{self.name} {self.rr}ч. {self.sm}тгр.'
        if self.role == 'Senior':
            self.sm = self.sm + (self.time * 20)
            return f'{self.name} {self.rr}ч. {self.sm}тгр.'
        if self.role == 'Milord':
            self.sm = (self.time * self.n) + self.sm
            return f'{self.name} {self.rr}ч. {self.sm}тгр.'
```

Итак, первые 4 проверки (включая указанную в примере) решение проходит, но дальше не принимает
Прошу помощи у знающих, что может быть не так?

Comment: Напиши для себя тесты. Например ситуация когда синьора повысили.

Comment: то, что Вы реализовали не имеет никакого отношения к ООП. Для того, чтобы решить задачу в парадигме ООП необходимо: 1. Создать абстрактный класс. 2. От этого класса сделать трех наследников. 3. Для каждого наследника реализовать нужные методы расчета зарплаты.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так. Вроде проходит

```
class Programmer:
def __init__(self, name, rank):
    self.name = name
    self.rank = rank
    
    self.worktime = 0
    self.salary = 0
    
    self.ranks = {
                'Junior': 10,
                'Middle': 15,
                'Senior': 20
                }
    
def work(self, worktime):
    self.worktime += worktime
    self.set_salary(self.rank, worktime)

def set_salary(self, rank, worktime):
    self.salary += worktime * self.ranks[rank]

def rise(self):
    if self.rank == 'Junior':
        self.rank = 'Middle'
    elif self.rank == 'Middle':
        self.rank = 'Senior'
    else:
        rank = self.ranks['Senior']
        rank += 1
        self.ranks.update({'Senior': rank})

def info(self):
    return f'{self.name} {self.worktime} {self.salary}'
```